# FCKEDITOR - Forçar todo texto a esquerda

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Como forçar um texto se inserido assim no FCKEDITOR:

```
Na frase: para discutir e levantar sugestões que possam trazer a solução definitiva.

      a)A sustentabilidade, que hoje tem caráter extremamente relevante, deve ser amplamente divulgada.
              b)É extremamente relevante que se estude a sustentabilidade e a natureza, que tem importância descomunal no futuro do ser humano.
 c)O homem é um ser que depende sobremaneira da natureza, pois é ela que lhe garante a vida.
               d)O meio ambiente, que hoje é bastante desrespeitado, é fator decisivo para a sobrevivência humana.
 e)Lixo, desperdício de matéria-prima, coleta seletiva e proteção dos mananciais são fatores que devem receber nossa atenção; entretanto, muitos ainda olham para isso com desinteresse.
```

Ele ficar alinhado a esquerda assim, forçadamente:

```
Na frase: para discutir e levantar sugestões que possam trazer a solução definitiva.

a)A sustentabilidade, que hoje tem caráter extremamente relevante, deve ser amplamente divulgada.
b)É extremamente relevante que se estude a sustentabilidade e a natureza, que tem importância descomunal no futuro do ser humano.
c)O homem é um ser que depende sobremaneira da natureza, pois é ela que lhe garante a vida.
d)O meio ambiente, que hoje é bastante desrespeitado, é fator decisivo para a sobrevivência humana.
e)Lixo, desperdício de matéria-prima, coleta seletiva e proteção dos mananciais são fatores que devem receber nossa atenção; entretanto, muitos ainda olham para isso com desinteresse.
```

Com JQUERY um amigo daqui conseguiu fazer e funcionou no textarea comum, mas com o FCKEDITOR não funciona.

Acho que achei uma forma. Eu tenho esse código em Jquery. Esse código alinha forçadamente qualquer texto a esquerda do textarea comum.

```
<script>
//ALINHA TEXTO A ESQUERDA
$("textarea#txt1").on('input',function(){
  var txt = $(this).val();
  var txt_novo = txt.replace(/(^|[\n\r])([\t\s])+/g, "$1");
  $(this).val(txt_novo);
});
</script>
```

E esse que faz iniciar a exibição do CKEDITOR:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#editor').ckeditor();  
    });
</script>
```

Como faço essa adaptação do Jquery no Fckeditor? Do código de cima no de baixo? Acredito que funcionara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#botao').on("click", function() {
    //retorna o texto do CKEDITOR
    var txt = (CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData());

    //se necessário, depende da versão do CKEDITOR
    var txt_novo = txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");

    txt_novo = txt_novo.replace(/(^|[\n\r])([\t\s])+/g, "$1");

    var instancia = (CKEDITOR.instances.editor);

    //coloca o novo texto no CKEDITOR  
    instancia.setData(txt_novo);

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="botao">Forçar todo texto a esquerda</button>
```

Comment: Ficou top demais. valeu a insistência, uma semana de luta. Coloquei a função no botão que envia o form, ai ele força a esquerda tudo, entra na regra que tenho em regex, separa a pergunta das respostas e insere no mysql. Show.

Comment: sem querer abusar cara. rs Tem como retirar (replace) nos  <brs> se eles vierem entre a letra a), b)... exemplo: a) <br> texto texto. Só o primeiro <br>

Comment: @Rod estava exatamente trabalhando com esse código e fazendo algumas variações veja em http://kithomepage.com/sos/FCKEDITOR-Forcar-todo-texto-a-esquerda2.html

Comment: Agora vou ter que sair mas olhe no código fonte e pesque o que lhe interessar

Comment: Estou querendo fazer o segundo  textarea hidden e mandar pro banco ao clicar em algum botão mas só depois que eu voltar

Answer (score 1):

O CKEditor não ouve `oninput`, apenas `onchange`.

O que você pode fazer é usar um botão para chamar uma função que irá fazer os ajustes, pegando o texto pela instância da API do editor.

Você pode usar um botão simples:

```
<button onclick="ajusta()">OK</button>
```

Ou se for enviar via `form`, coloque um retorno com `onsubmit`:

```
<form onsubmit="return ajusta()">
   ...
</form>
```

**Função:**

```
function ajusta(){
   var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.questao; // pega a instância
   var txt = editor.getData(); // pega o texto
   var txt_novo = txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g,''); // remove os &nbsp;
   txt_novo = txt_novo.replace(/(^|[\n\r])([\t\s])+/g, ''); // remove as quebras de linha + espaço
   editor.setData(txt_novo); // atualiza o texto no editor
}
```

Comment: vcs são demais...usei a configuração inline do ckeditor, onde limpa os htmls todos, só permite os <brs> em default.

Comment: @dvd com isso, o texto já vai todo a esquerda, sem possibilidade de erro do usuario.

Comment: Dei um jeito no meu doido ckeditor e agora  tá do jeito que quero. http://kithomepage.com/sos/FCKEDITOR-Forcar-todo-texto-a-esquerda2.html SEM tags HTML, BODY, TITLE etc... todas as tags são retiradas